# 'let' doesn't memoize values in rsepc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have a user model, who have a many-to-many relationship whit itself: user A add user B as a friend, and automatically, user B becomes friend of user A too.

Performing the following steps in the rails console:

1) Create two users and save them:

```
2.3.1 :002 > u1 = User.new(name: "u1", email: "u1@mail.com")
 => #<User _id: 5788eae90640fd10cc85f291, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, friend_ids: nil, name: "u1", email: "u1@mail.com"> 
2.3.1 :003 > u1.save
 => true 
2.3.1 :004 > u2 = User.new(name: "u2", email: "u2@mail.com")
 => #<User _id: 5788eaf80640fd10cc85f292, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, friend_ids: nil, name: "u2", email: "u2@mail.com"> 
2.3.1 :005 > u2.save
 => true
```

2) Add user u2 as friend of u1:

```
2.3.1 :006 > u1.add_friend u2
 => [#<User _id: 5788eaf80640fd10cc85f292, created_at: 2016-07-15 13:54:04 UTC, updated_at: 2016-07-15 13:55:19 UTC, friend_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('5788eae90640fd10cc85f291')], name: "u2", email: "u2@mail.com">]
```

3) Check their friendship:

```
2.3.1 :007 > u1.friend? u2
 => true 
2.3.1 :008 > u2.friend? u1
 => true
```

As we can see, the "mutual friendship" works. But in my tests that doesn't happen. Here are my tests:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do    
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:other_user) { create(:user) }

  context "when add a friend" do
    it "should put him in friend's list" do
      user.add_friend(other_user)
      expect(user.friend? other_user).to be_truthy
    end

    it "should create a friendship" do
      expect(other_user.friend? user).to be_truthy
    end
  end
end
```

Here are the tests result:

```
Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:33 # User when add a friend should create a friendship
```

The only reason that I can see to the second test is failing is because my `let` is not memoizing the association to use in other tests. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my User model, for reference:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :posts
  has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, class_name: "User",
                           inverse_of: :friends, dependent: :nullify

  field :name, type: String
  field :email, type: String

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true

  index({ email: 1 })

  def friend?(user)
    friends.include?(user)
  end

  def add_friend(user)
    friends << user
  end

  def remove_friend(user)
    friends.delete(user)
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you mean 'memoize'?

Comment: Right, @Sid. Question updated.

Comment: What strategy are you using to clean the database for your tests? You might need to add the `user.add_friend(other_user)` to a `before { }` so it happens before each example. The most common strategies clear the DB after every example.

Comment: Those 2 `let`s should probably go inside of your `context` block. You likely won't need to `create` a user record for every model test that you write for your user. (Sometimes you may want to `build` instead so you don't have to hit the database to test things like validations.)

Comment: Also, your `context` assumes that those users will definitely be created, so you'll probably want to change both `let`s to `let!`. It just makes it easier to understand what's going on over the long term of your project, even if what you are currently running "works."

Comment: Indeed, @Leito. Now I see that my problem happens because my db clean strategy. It's cleaning the db after every example.

Comment: @ChrisPeters, understood. In this case I can't use ``build`` instead ``create``. Check my third step in the question. If I run ``u2.friend? u1``, returns ``false`` if the object aren't saved (that doesn't seems a natural behavior to me, but I don't know how change that).

Comment: I'm simply stating that the `creates` should happen inside of the `context` block, not the global `RSpec.describe` block. That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the creation of the relationship into a `before` block:

```
context "when add a friend" do
  before do
    user.add_friend(other_user)
  end

  it "should put him in friend's list" do
    expect(user.friend? other_user).to be_truthy
  end

  it "should create a friendship" do
    expect(other_user.friend? user).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

In your code, you are only running it within the first `it` block, to the second one starts from scratch and it's not run.

With the `before` block, it is run once before each of the `it` blocks, so the spec should pass then.